# Generating documentation for python script with Doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm trying to create some documentation for some Python scripts included in my project (the rest is Fortran/C). I managed to include a brief and a detailed description for the files, but all the variables defined in the script are being listed in the documentation.

How do I avoid them from being listed? Which variable in the Doxyfile controls the inclusion of all the variables of a file?

Comment: How are you setting up Doxygen for your Python files? What are the specifics for your Python files? Are all your variables global? Are you using a Doxygen filter for Python like doxypypy?

Comment: My Python files are just scripts supposed to be launched interactively from the command line, with dynamic declaration of global variables (as a consequence in my doxygen documentation I get all the lines where a variable is declared for the first time). And yes, I'm using doxypy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this similar problem while working with python-Doxygen. What worked for me is to enclose your variables between \cond and \endcond.

For example,

```
## \cond
some_var = "abc"
## \endcond
```

They won't show up in your documentation :)